# Remove extra white spaces at the bottom of <div><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div> tags

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11, popper.js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

ul {
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!------- START :: SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS --------->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card toggle-card">
      <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" href="#SYSTEMREQUIREMENTS" role="button">
        <h3 class="toggle-card-closed">The minimum system requirements are:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="SYSTEMREQUIREMENTS">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>p_1</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_2</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
            <li>li_2</li>
            <li><strong>li_3</strong></li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_3</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
            <li>li_2</li>
            <li>li_3</li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_4</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_5</p>
          <p><strong><u>p_6</u></strong></p>
          <p>p_7</p>

          <p>p_8</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
            <li>li_2</li>
          </ul>
          <p><a href="#top">Back to top</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above is my exact code block, with substituted text.  This is what it looks like:
[image: How it looks in IE11.]

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image: How I want it to look.]

This "extra" white space on the bottom accumulates in each ul tag with multiple `li`.  If there is only one `li`, the white space doesn't accumulate.

I have multiple `div class="row" div class="col" div class="card toggle-card"` sections and this section is the only one that has that extra white space.  It is absolutely due to the multiple `li` in a `ul` tag because I have backed out and debugged to the bare minimum.

*Disclaimer: This appears to be an IE issue only; tested with IE11.  I have tried in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox with zero issues.*

Comment: I just tried it with ie11 and get the expected results

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap 4.1.3 and popper.

Comment: Thanks, I missed your edit.  I added my libraries up top.

Comment: I had added those already.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your question is (or where the whitespace is, I can't see it), but I have fixed many problems like yours by adding `class="mb-0"` to whatever element is being a problem.  This is especially common (for me) on `<p>` tags.

**Update**: My first answer still stands.  Change `<li>` to `<li class="mb-0">`.

```css
h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

ul {
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!------- START :: SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS --------->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card toggle-card">
      <div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" href="#SYSTEMREQUIREMENTS" role="button">
        <h3 class="toggle-card-closed">The minimum system requirements are:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="SYSTEMREQUIREMENTS">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>p_1</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_2</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
            <li>li_2</li>
            <li><strong>li_3</strong></li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_3</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
            <li>li_2</li>
            <li>li_3</li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_4</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
          </ul>

          <p>p_5</p>
          <p><strong><u>p_6</u></strong></p>
          <p>p_7</p>

          <p>p_8</p>
          <ul>
            <li>li_1</li>
            <li>li_2</li>
          </ul>
          <p class="mb-0"><a href="#top" class="mb-0">Back to top</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED** to actually fix the problem

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.  I did post pictures in the question, so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: @SupraFast  Ok.  It's really hard to tell from those pictures what's wrong, I can't  really see a difference.  Could you update them with highlighted areas?  Again, it seems almost exactly the same.

Comment: @ Ka_ren Look at the very bottom of the pictures.  The white space from "Back to the top" and down is the problem.

Comment: Oh!  That's easy @SupraFast .  Add `class="mb-0"` or `class="m-0"` inside of the `p` and `a` tags

Comment: I just tried it @ Ka_ren . Unfortunately it didn't do anything.

Comment: It would help if you only use bootstrap 4.1.3, since  you also had 2.1.1 in your code @SupraFast

Comment: @ Ka_ren I am using 4.1.3. Someone edited my post and added whatever is above <!------- START :: SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS ---------> My libraries are st the very top.